# node.js asnyc get from object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object being used as an enum in node:

```
var ExEnum = function() {
  this.obj1 = { name: 'obj1', id: 1, value: null }
  this.obj2 = { name: 'obj2', id: 2, value: null }
}
```

Values are instantiated as `null` but over the course of program life will update as the current value from an input. These values are accessed from via request and I currently use the function `getValueFromId` in the object prototype.

```
ExEnum.prototype = {
  getValueFromId: function(num) {
    for (var key in this) {
      if (this[key].hasOwnProperty('id') && this[key].id == num) {
        return this[key].value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`getValueFromId` is a synchronous function, it is called in a loop that passes along values to the clients that request that information like this:

```
var res = exEnum.getValuesFromId(arr[i].points);
arr[i].socket.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

What effect does the synchronous call have on the program and how do I convert it to a synchronous function?

Comment: Why do you want it to be async?

Comment: I am not 100% sure that answer will depend on how a synchronous call could change the behavior of the program.

Comment: You usually would want IO or really long operations to be non-blocking. I don't think that this function is going to change the performance or the behavior of the program at all, but maybe I'm just not understanding the problem here.

Comment: I see your point. In practice ExEnum is 249 objects long. On the other end, there will likely be no more than 12 connections requesting information. So for example, if the values were stored in a DB, I would want this in a non-blocking fashion?

Comment: your function will return only single value, there is no point for any loop. you can just `return this['obj'+num].value; `